# Disable high watermark-Log entries in sonarqube 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I have a little problem with sonarqube 5.6 I got the error:

```
high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [dGbc0mfEQmOT5LXYQU45aQ][sonar-1498565081006] free: 931mb[5.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node
high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [dGbc0mfEQmOT5LXYQU45aQ][sonar-1498565081006] free: 931mb[5.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

in the sonar.log which I would like to disable (or at least decrease the limit). And after a little search I found out that I have to run this command

```
curl --noproxy '*' --u admin:admin -vvvv -XPUT http://localhost:9004/_cluster/settings -d '{"persistent" : {"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": False}}'
```

but when I do this I got a 404-Error and I have no idea why this don't work. That's why I would very thanksful if someone can give me a little hint what I am doing wrong? The sonarqube-Installation is running on SuSE.
best regards
Dan

Comment: It's telling you you're running out of disk space.

Comment: I know but I would like to disable it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message indicates than there is not enough free disk space on your server, so the best fix is to free some space.

Your curl request is not working because you need to start SonarQube with this property set :
`sonar.search.httpPort=10000`

and use this port (without any authentication `-u admin:admin`) in your curl request.

And then remove this property and restart SonarQube.

*Please note that overriding this value is not supported.*

Comment: Yes I understand the meaning of this message, but there are two problems first if this message appear normally more than 5 GB free space on this device left. The second I use other monitoring Tools for the watching that I don't run out of space
I will try this and would like to thank you for your help till this point